# MVC 3 issue when model binding checkbox through AJAX rather than postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an issue with model binding a checkbox from a form to an action on the server with a custom object containing a boolean.

Doing a google there seems to be a lot of problems with this, and no good solution. I have tried multiple things, and the problem seems to only happen when it is sent through an ajax call rather than a normal postback.

I have the following in my project (cut down for brevity):

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TillAccess)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.TillAccess)
```

**Model**

```
public class CreateUserModel 
{
    public Boolean TillAccess { get; set; } 
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult CreateUserWizard(CreateUserModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

I have added 2 buttons to the form, one sends as a postback and works. It sends the following with a postback if I check it on fiddler2:

```
TillAccess=true&TillAccess=false
```

It sends the following if I send it with the ajax button, and doesnt work:

```
{"TillAccess":["true","false"]}
```

Is there an issue with the way MVC model binds JSON that stops this working??

I can't get this working through AJAX (which I will be using heavily), every other field binds fine, just not the checkbox, and the fact this works perfect as a normal postback suggests its an issue with the JSON serialiser or model binder for MVC?

UPDATE

The ajax call is as follows:

```
function CreateUser() {
        var FormData = JSON.stringify($('#CreateUserWizardForm').serializeObject());

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action(MVC.User.User.ActionNames.CreateUserWizard)',
            data: FormData,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            cache: 'false',
            success: function (response) {
                alert('successfully created user!');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('There was an error creating a user');
            }
        });
    }
```

Full ajax post is as follows just fyi:

```
{"BusinessUnitId":"cd56b710-0171-11e1-be50-0800200c9a66","Person.Salutation":"","Person.FirstName":"","Person.LastName":"","‌​TillAccess":["true","false"],"OfficeAccess":"false","TillLoginId":"","OfficeEmail‌​Address":"","OfficePassword":""}
```

UPDATE

The serializeObject method was downloaded from the internet (as I was having json issues with the post) and is as follows:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

UPDATE

The reason I used this serializeObject method was due to an error I received if I used the inbuilt call of:

```
$('#CreateUserWizardForm').serialize()
```

It created a post of:

```
BusinessUnitId=cd56b710-0171-11e1-be50-0800200c9a66&Person.Salutation=&Person.FirstName=&Person.LastName=&TillAccess=true&TillAccess=false&OfficeAccess=false&TillLoginId=&OfficeEmailAddress=&OfficePassword=
```

Which gave me an error as follows:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: BusinessUnitId.
```

**UPDATE - ANSWER (I tried to add my answer at the bottom, but it won't let me)**

**I found the solution. It was my AJAX call that was wrong. I changed it to the following and it is working.**

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action(MVC.User.User.ActionNames.CreateUserWizard)',
            data: $('#CreateUserWizardForm').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            cache: 'false',
            success: function (response) {
                alert('successfully created user!');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('There was an error creating a user');
            }
        });
```

The old AJAX call:

```
var FormData = JSON.stringify($('#CreateUserWizardForm').serializeObject());

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action(MVC.User.User.ActionNames.CreateUserWizard)',
            data: FormData,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            cache: 'false',
            success: function (response) {
                alert('successfully created user!');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('There was an error creating a user');
            }
        });
```

Comment: try changing the `serializeObject` function to use the `id` of the input rather than the `name`. `Html.CheckBoxFor` creates a 2nd input without an `id` but has the same `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It was my AJAX call that was wrong. I changed it to the following and it is working.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action(MVC.User.User.ActionNames.CreateUserWizard)',
            data: $('#CreateUserWizardForm').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            cache: 'false',
            success: function (response) {
                alert('successfully created user!');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('There was an error creating a user');
            }
        });
```

The old AJAX call:

```
var FormData = JSON.stringify($('#CreateUserWizardForm').serializeObject());

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action(MVC.User.User.ActionNames.CreateUserWizard)',
            data: FormData,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            cache: 'false',
            success: function (response) {
                alert('successfully created user!');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('There was an error creating a user');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send

```
{"model":{"TillAccess":["true","false"]}}
```

The model binder is not binding your model because it cannot match `model` parameter with any property.

UPDATE:

`TillAccess` property is of type `bool`, but you're sending an array of 2 strings. I think this is a problem

Comment: I can't see that being the issue, as this Json is auto generated for me by the framework, and every other field is bound correctly. The full post is as follows: {"BusinessUnitId":"cd56b710-0171-11e1-be50-0800200c9a66","Person.Salutation":"","Person.FirstName":"","Person.LastName":"","TillAccess":["true","false"],"OfficeAccess":"false","TillLoginId":"","OfficeEmailAddress":"","OfficePassword":""}

Comment: Again, this is not something that I am generating, it is the serialise method for the ajax side of it. i.e. I am doing "var FormData = JSON.stringify($('#CreateUserWizardForm').serializeObject());"

Comment: It means that your `$('#CreateUserWizardForm').serializeObject()` returns wrong JSON.

Comment: I believe the `serializeObject()` is creating the json as a result of `@Html.CheckBoxFor` creating two html elements with the same name attribute

Comment: Ah, I have just noticed that the serializeObject() method is something I copied from the internet, and not something inbuilt to jQuery. I will post the function above in my post. Also, I'm sure I added this method call as the Json was not being built correctly by default.

Comment: Yeah there are 2 checkboxes output to the form due to the Razor method to create the checkbox, and it is adding both values. This must be a common issue though. Sending a checkbox that was created by Razor, to the server through AJAX.

Comment: I have now found the solution to this problem, and I have updated the original question, until the forum lets me add a response.